# Reset checkboxes in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-checkbox, android-sharedpreferences

I have 3 fragments with 3 recycler views. I save the checkbox state by shared pref. I want to be able to reset the checkboxes on button click. This is where I try to reset the checkboxes on button click:

```
public class HomeActivity extends BaseActivity {

private Button mButton;
SharedPreferences prefs;
Context mContext;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_all_layout);
    activateToolbar();
    setUpNavigationDrawer();
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Shieko Workout");

    prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("checkstate", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

    mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            prefs.edit().remove("checkstate");
            prefs.edit().commit();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Checkboxes Cleared.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
}
```

And here is where I save them.

```
   @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.exercise.setText(workout.get(position).getExercise());
    holder.percent.setText(workout.get(position).getPercent());
    holder.reps.setText(workout.get(position).getReps());
    holder.weight.setText(workout.get(position).getWeight());
    holder.check1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);

    final Workout isCheck = workout.get(position);

    holder.check1.setChecked(isCheck.isCheck1());
    prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("checkstate", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    holder.check1.setChecked(prefs.getBoolean(firstSecondOrThird+"checkState"+position, false));
    isCheck.setCheck1(prefs.getBoolean(firstSecondOrThird+"checkState"+position, false));
holder.check1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            isCheck.setCheck1(isChecked);
            prefs.edit().putBoolean(firstSecondOrThird+"checkState"+position, isChecked).apply();
        }
    });

}
```

I get no error, but when I click the button then go back to the recycler views, the items are still clicked! thanks!

edit: I think i have to notify the adapter of the change, but not sure how as this button is in a separate class.

Comment: Just to understand, you are not touching the checkbox itself but a button, who change the state of the object `Workout` is that correct ? If it's the case, i think you will need create a new list with the new state, remove and  add the list to the adapter. The `notifyDataSetChanged()` only work for remove or add objects, not change the state of the object itself.

Comment: I think that the problem is in the adapter, you must set the checked(false) and checked(true) when you're inflating the items of recyclerview.

Comment: The list by default is not checked, I then save each items checkmark as it becomes checked so it stays. I thought that my code above, where I'm clearing the saved state, would reset all checkboxes to unchecked, as it's no longer being saved in shared pref, for some reason it's not working though...